# Google Sheets get an average value from unique values in a single column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On Google Sheets, I want to find an average for all values in rows that contain a unique value in one column.
For example, I have a sheet like this:

- Dog |   2
- Dog |   1
- Dog |   4
- Cat |   3
- Rat |  2
- Cat |    1

And I want to create another table below it for the average value of each unique value in the row:

- Dog |    2.33
- Cat  |   2
- Rat | 2

Comment: This is a typical task for a Pivot Table. Do you have headers? If so, have a look at [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Use column one as your rows, column two as values and set it to `AVERAGE`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:B7;"SELECT A, AVG(B) GROUP BY A")
```

assuming your data (containing titles) are on the A and B columns of the sheet.